# Don't import my custom models form models package

Tags: go

I have no error and I don't know why I can access my model from models packages.
I use module also, here is my go.mod file:

---

```
module myapp

go 1.12

require (
    github.com/badoux/checkmail v0.0.0-20181210160741-9661bd69e9ad
    github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go v3.2.0+incompatible
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.7.3
    github.com/jinzhu/gorm v1.9.11
    github.com/joho/godotenv v1.3.0
    github.com/rs/cors v1.7.0
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20191108234033-bd318be0434a
)
```

---

`user.go` and `car.go` are importing fine but not the rest of the new models that I add are not importing well.

Here is the tree of my app:

```
├── api
│   ├── auth
│   │   └── token.go
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── base.go
│   │   ├── car_location_controller.go
│   │   ├── cars_controller.go
│   │   ├── login_controller.go
│   │   ├── routers.go
│   │   └── users_controller.go
│   ├── middlewares
│   │   └── middlewares.go
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── Car.go
│   │   ├── CarLocation.go
│   │   ├── Rental.go
│   │   └── User.go
│   ├── responses
│   │   └── json.go
│   ├── server.go
│   └── utils
│       └── formaterror
│           └── formaterror.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── info.txt
└── main.go
```

I try to call `CarLocation.go` into `car_location_controller.go` but I got

> CarLocation not declared by package models

Here is my CarLocation.go:

```
package models

import (
    "errors"
    "html"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

type CarLocation struct {
    ID        uint32    `gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment" json:"id"`
    CarID     uint32    `gorm:"int" json:"user_id"`
    Car       Car       `json:"car"`
    Street    string    `json:"street"`
    City      string    `json:"city"`
    State     string    `json:"state"`
    Country   string    `json:"country"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"updated_at"`
}

func (l *CarLocation) Prepare() {
    l.ID = 0
    l.Street = html.EscapeString(strings.TrimSpace(l.Street))
    l.City = html.EscapeString(strings.TrimSpace(l.City))
    l.State = html.EscapeString(strings.TrimSpace(l.State))
    l.CreatedAt = time.Now()
    l.UpdatedAt = time.Now()
}

func (cl *CarLocation) Validate() error {
    if cl.Street == "" {
        return errors.New("Required Street")
    }
    if cl.City == "" {
        return errors.New("Required City")
    }

    if cl.State == "" {
        return errors.New("Required State")
    }

    return nil
}
```

And here is where I want to use CarLocation into `car_location_controller.go`:

```
package controllers

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"

    "myapp/api/responses"
    "myapp/api/models"
)

func (server *Server) CreateCarLocation(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        responses.ERROR(w, http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, err)
        return
    }
    car := models.CarLocation{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &car)
    if err != nil {
        responses.ERROR(w, http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, err)
        return
    }

    car.Prepare()
}
```

Comment: Sorry it was VSCODE bad configuration + some duplicated methods from car_controller.go

All is ok , go mod importas all my packages.

Comment: could be more useful to detail the VSCODE confiruration update you applied.

Comment: In Visual Code go to Settings, Search for GO and activate:
GO: Autocomplete Unimported Packages